# FloatingActionButton doesn't seem to work with whatever library I use

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

I wanted to implement a floating action button in android studio and I followed all the steps: Adding dependencies, adding the xmlns to the layout and making the floatingbuttion in the xml as follows:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/primary"
    fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/accent"
    fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/primary_dark" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

but in the preview I got a gray, empty square. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use the floating action button form the android support design library

Comment: 1. Why don't you use the FAB from the support library?

2. What does not work?

Comment: It shows a gray square in the preview.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: It says I need to have at least 10 rep

Comment: Look at my answer for more :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think you have to include a `src`
Please reply if it helped you!

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/recyclerview" />
```

Comment: still a gray square :(

Answer (score 0):

Please add the code "app:borderWidth="0dp" as property.